# How to properly generate TopoJSON for California Population Density

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geojson, shapefile, topojson

I've been trying to follow Mike Bostock's California Population Density example: bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5562380

I cloned his Git repo and took his counties.shp for California, and then I went to the Census.gov website to download the latest 2015 tract files for California.

I then ran the following command on **both** shapefiles to reproject them:

```
ogr2ogr \
    -f 'ESRI Shapefile' \
    -t_srs 'EPSG:3310' \
    counties.shp \
    shp/ca/counties.shp

ogr2ogr \
    -f 'ESRI Shapefile' \
    -t_srs 'EPSG:3310' \
    tracts.shp \
    shp/ca/cb_2015_06_tract_500k.shp
```

After this, I ran the following TopoJSON command:

```
topojson
    -e ACS_14_5YR_B01003_with_ann.csv \
    --id-property GEOID,GEO.id2 \
    -p population=+HD01_VD01,area=+ALAND \
    -s 1 \
    --width 960 \
    --margin 10 \
    -o ca.json \
    -- tracts.shp counties.shp
```

Here are my files (shapefiles w/ ca.json): http://dropcanvas.com/akgqb

However, my output is unlike Mike's ca.json: **the 'population' property is missing aside of the 'area' property:** https://paste.ee/p/RGApI

I have no idea what I am doing wrong. I may be using the TopoJSON command wrong for my particular files.

I've been struggling with this for a couple days, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you do not provide all the shp-related files, I can only assume that you may have to remove the "+" symbols from the topojson command. These attributes are already integers in the cvs file. Try it and let me know if it works. 
Another possible problem is the second line in your CSV file. This may be unnecessary. Try to delete it and rerun the command.
Or just upload the rest of the files so we can check the commands properly.

Comment: Alright, so I removed the "+" symbols and re-ran the command, still no 'population' property. I also removed the second line of the CSV file and still no 'population' property. I will provide you the files. Make sure you run **all** the commands that I did to reproduce the counties.shp and tracts.shp. Here are the files: http://dropcanvas.com/gcvvb

Comment: sTheod, I have solved the problem! No need to help anymore! If anyone is having my problem, just edit the CSV file and rename the first column key to: **AFFGEOID** and then edit the TopoJSON command to this: `topojson -e ACS_14_5YR_B01003_with_ann.csv --id-property AFFGEOID -p population=+HD01_VD01,area=+ALAND -s 1 --width 960 --margin 10 -o ca.json -- tracts.shp counties.shp` Cheers.

Comment: Yes, it was the two arguments that you provided in --id-property apparently!

Comment: Yeah, very subtle. I noticed this after converting the shapefiles to TopoJSON and noticing that the geographic IDs were different. Maybe the Census.gov site decided to change the property names within the past years. It'd be nice if Mike Bostock updated the tutorial.